# Symfony3 execute phpmetrics

Tags: php, symfony

Installed phpmetrics with my Symfony3 project by following the docs: [Metrics docs](https://github.com/phpmetrics/PhpMetrics).

Now that i have installed it with composer and the phpmetrics binaries are avalible in bin/ directory am trying to actually run it. The problem I am getting is that every time i run this command `phpmetrics --report-html=myreport.html /path/of/your/sources` i get this error:

```
[LogicException]
  No file found
```

I have tried all of these:

```
bin/phpmetrics --report-html=myreport.html ../src/User/UserBundle/Controller/AuthenticationController.php
bin/phpmetrics --report-html=myreport.html src/User/UserBundle/Controller/AuthenticationController.php
bin/phpmetrics --report-html=myreport.html /User/UserBundle/Controller/AuthenticationController.php
bin/phpmetrics --report-html=myreport.html UserBundle/Controller/AuthenticationController.php
bin/phpmetrics --report-html=myreport.html Controller/AuthenticationController.php
```

Always the the same error.

Comment: Input absolute directory/file path, not relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because the library is installed in the vendor directory (as symfony standard) BUT `vendor` is one of the directories [excluded by default](https://github.com/phpmetrics/PhpMetrics/blob/cb5cdc6f6cd6eb5e6661cbdd00e17ed57fa3e578/src/Hal/Application/Config/TreeBuilder.php#L48). Passing another value as option should may solve your problem. As example:

```
phpmetrics --excluded-dirs=_none_  --report-html=myreport.html
```

Hope this help

More info in [this github issue](https://github.com/phpmetrics/PhpMetrics/issues/176)

Comment: ok so this seems to work but says `Generating Summary HTML Report...
Done` but where do i see this report..?

Comment: owww i got it had to refresh my project the report gets stored in root dir :P thank you

Comment: ok actually i can see the file but how do i view thats file out of symfony root dir?